# Push Notification in PhoneGAP using Eclipse (Push Plugin) : Didn't get Registration ID

Tags: javascript, eclipse, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I am working on PhoneGAP using Eclipse and Implemented **Push Plugin**  https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSampleApp that return Sucess :OK but I didnt get Registration Id.

and It didnt hit the **onNotification()** function as i placed the Alert to check it.

CODE:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        var pushNotification;

        function onDeviceReady() {

            alert("Device Ready");
           // $('#lblRegistrationId').text("Device Ready Fired");

            ///////reached
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

                if( $("#home").length > 0)
                {
                    // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                    //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
                else
                {
                    navigator.app.backHistory();
                }
            }, false);

            try 
            { 
                pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

              ///////reached

               $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');

                if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' || device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' ) {




                   pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","ecb":"onNotification"});       // required!



                }

                 else {
                    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                }
            }
            catch(err) 
            { 
                txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                alert(txt); 
            } 
        }

        // handle APNS notifications for iOS
        function onNotificationAPN(e) {
            if (e.alert) {
                 $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
                 // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
                 navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
            }

            if (e.sound) {
                // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                var snd = new Media(e.sound);
                snd.play();
            }

            if (e.badge) {
                pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
            }
        }

        // handle GCM notifications for Android
        function onNotification(e) {

            alert("GCM RESPONSE");

            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

            switch( e.event )
            {
                case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    alert("Registered");

                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                    // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                    // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                    console.log("regID = " + e.regid);

                     alert("regID = " + e.regid);

                     $('#lblRegistrationId').text("regID = " + e.regid);

                }
                break;

                case 'message':
                    // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                    // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                    if (e.foreground)
                    {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                            // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
                                // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                                var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                                // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                                // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                                var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);

                        my_media.play();
                    }
                    else
                    {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                        if (e.coldstart)
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        else
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    }

                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                    //android only
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                    //amazon-fireos only
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
                break;

                case 'error':
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                break;

                default:
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                break;
            }
        }

        function tokenHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
            // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
        }

        function successHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
        }

        function errorHandler (error) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
        }

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

     </script>


    <div id="home">
        <div id="app-status-div">
            <ul id="app-status-ul">
                <li>Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


     <div id="DivForm">
     <label id="lblRegistrationId"></label>
      <input name="submit" id="btnRegistration" type="button" value="Submit" onclick=""/>

     </div>
```

Need Help in this regard :( ...I created Project on google console and placed the ProjectId as sender ID

Comment: please specify which js files you have already included?

Comment: **PushNotification.js** ,**jquery_1.5.2.min.js** and  **cordova-2.5.0.js**

Comment: Hope you have already added Device, Dialogs, network information, media, gobalization and file plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Following code is working properly. Check it out and see if u have done any mistake. Feel free to ask me if u have any doubt.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div id="app-status-div">
            <ul id="app-status-ul">
                <li>Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var pushNotification;

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

        function onDeviceReady()
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

                if( $("#home").length > 0)
                {
                    // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                    //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                } 
                else
                {
                    navigator.app.backHistory();
                }
            }, false);

            try
            {
                pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');

                if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ||  device.platform == 'amazon-fireos')
                {
                    pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX","ecb":"onNotification"});       // required!
                } 
                else 
                {
                    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                }
            } 
            catch(err)
            {
                txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n";
                txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
                alert(txt); 
            }
        }

        // handle APNS notifications for iOS


        // handle GCM notifications for Android
        function onNotification(e) 
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

            switch( e.event )
            {
                case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                    // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                    // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                    console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
                }
                break;

                case 'message':
                    // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                    // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                    if (e.foreground)
                    {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                            // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
                                // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                                var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                                // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                                var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);

                        my_media.play();
                    }
                    else
                    {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                        if (e.coldstart)
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        else
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    }

                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                    //android only
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                    //amazon-fireos only
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
                break;

                case 'error':
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                break;

                default:
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                break;
            }
        }

        function tokenHandler (result)
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
            // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
        }

        function successHandler (result)
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
        } 

        function errorHandler (error)
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
        }
      </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code ,mine code also worked  ....problem is with my device .I run the code on another one and it works :). Thanks alot